# Wordpress: Does get_post_meta() query the database while in the loop?

Tags: database, wordpress, post, meta

Does get_post_meta() query the database while in the loop?

During search results (in the loop) I have a series of values I grab post meta for.

example:

```
<?php
$post_meta_array = array(
    'this',
    'that',
    'more',
    'stuff'
);

foreach ($post_meta_array as $get_meta) {

    $stuff_just_got = get_post_meta($get_meta, '');

}
?>
```

I was under the impress that get_post_meta() does not need to query the  database while in the loop. I'm double checking to see if that is the case. If its not the case...ouch.

Comment: Look at your general query log and find out. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-log.html

Comment: Neat-o I've never heard of this.

Comment: If you have caching set up (and you should) then it may or may not hit the database. Preloading every meta value for every post in the loop would be very expensive - some posts have hundreds - so it will fetch them as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Good answer above, and accidentally stumbled on this one: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/debug-queries/ for checking queries.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'ls_redirect', true);
```

ls_redirect is a meta key